# How to refer to dynamically created directory in another task with ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook which checkouts the svn repo to the directory created with 
`"{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M') }}"`
and I refer to the same directory in subsequent tasks, but some time due to network latency or some other reasons new directory is created rather than referred directory.
Below is my Playbook.

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: tag_name_test
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  vars:
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M') }}"
    #dir: "/var/www/"
  tasks:
    - name:  Task 1: svn import
      subversion:
        username: username
        password: password
        repo: http:repoURL
        dest: /var/www/test-{{ date }}
        export: yes
        force: yes
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: Task 2: Change Permission
      file:
        path: /var/www/test-{{ date }}
        owner: apache
        group: apache
        mode: '0770'
        recurse: true
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: Task 3: Creating Link
      file:
        src: /var/www/test-{{ date }}
        dest: /var/www/test
        state: link
      ignore_errors: yes
```

How can we refer the directory created on Task 1: to subsequent tasks which will not change with the changing time.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'defining' your variable you should have made it a fact (`set_fact`). Your variable is indeed a *variable* as the lookup will be executed everytime you access your variable. Thats why your timestamp may change during playbook execution.

So instead of using

```
vars:
  date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M') }}"
```

you should use a task

```
- name: Get date
  set_fact:
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M') }}"
```

This will execute the lookup only while the fact creation and save it as variable `date`. When you now refer to `date` it will use the stored fact and that will not change within the play.

Comment: Perfect solution, Thank you very much.